# CSS: positioning image in relation to background image

Tags: css, positioning

I'd like to position a logo and menu on a site with an x-repeating background and I'd like those two to always be displayed in the same area of the background (there's a brighter stripe on the background and the logo should always be within that, while the menu items should be a bit below it).

As the logo and menu images scale according to screen size and the background just repeats I can't get it to work on the y-axis - any idea how to do this?

The page is sarahreesbrennan-fans (dot) com - you'll see what I mean if you take a look. (this is just to see what I'm talking about in case somebody can't imagine it from the description).

My code for the page is:

```
<div id="bg_wrapper"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/floral.png" /></div>
<div id="logo"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/logo1.png" width="50%" /></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
color: #444444;
font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 10pt;
background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/page-back.gif) repeat-x #22221f;
}
#bg_wrapper {
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
width:100%;
text-align:center
}
#logo {
padding-top: 3%;
padding-left: 3%;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like your new, you should edit your post and place your code attempt & if possible a jsFiddle.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Thanks, hope that's ok now

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make the div the right height and to center the image vertically in the div.

```
#logo {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 3%;
  height:128px; line-height:128px;
}
#logo img {vertical-align:middle;}
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n3GVR/).

(Note, in the fiddle I also removed the `width:100%` from the `#bg_wrapper`, as this had the effect of causing a horizontal scrollbar to appear even when the window was wide enough.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried this, and the approach is exactly what I need, but the img won't respond to the vertical-align... Any ideas why?

Comment: PS: Without the width:100%, the floral pattern won't be centered... I set it to 99% now, so that the scroll bar is gone but if you have any better solution for this, I'd also be glad to hear it - thanks!

Comment: The img won't respond to the vertical align? That's odd; it does on my computer: if I remove it the image jumps upwards. Do you have other styles defined on these elements than the ones you mentioned in your question?

Comment: No, played around with it for at least two hours, but it didn't work. I solved it differently now, though, just adding an empty element above it. Thanks a lot, though!